# Optimizing SQL View to Avoid Cartesian Product

Tags: sql, view, mariadb

I have a set of test scripts (approximately 4,000 unique scripts) that run periodically and write their results to a table (script_history) in a mariadb database.  That table currently has 60,000 rows.  In order to view the most recent record of the 4,000 scripts, I have a view that written as:

```
SELECT
   t1.pk ASK pk,
   t1.script_name AS script_name, 
   t1.test_points_passed AS test_points_passed,
   t1.test_points_failed AS test_points_failed,
   t1.execution_time AS execution_time,
   t1.tester_name AS tester_name,
   t1.execution_date as execution_date,
   t1.test_notes AS test_notes,
   t1.script_in_execution AS script_in_execution,
   t1.hostname AS hostname
FROM
   (script_db.script_history t1 LEFT JOIN script_db.script_history t2 ON
    (t2.script_name = t1.script_name and t2.execution_date > t1.execution_date))
WHERE t2.execution_date IS NULL group by t1.script_name
```

This provides the record of the most recent run of each of the 4,000 scripts.  Unfortunately it is producing a cartesian product which is severely degrading performance when trying to load the view (taking almost 5 minutes to load).

I have also tried the following for the view:

```
SELECT
   script_history.*
FROM
   (SELECT
      pk, script_name, test_points_passed, test_points_failed, execution_time, tester_name, MAX(execution_date)
      as execution_date, test_notes, script_in_execution, hostname
   FROM script_history
   GROUP BY script_name) AS A
INNER JOIN
   script_history
   ON
     script_history.script_name = A.script_name AND
     script_history.execution_date = A.execution_date;
```

This view definition will load extremely fast, unfortunately it does not seem to produce the desired result.  Instead of the last run data of each of the 4000 unique scripts, it introduces duplicates (around 400 records) where the same script was run on the same day, producing some 4,400 records in this view.  Any help to get a view with row data of the last execution of a group of scripts would be appreciated.

**Sample Data:**
(pk, script_name, test points passed, test points failed, execution time,
tester, execution date, test notes,script in execution, hostname)

```
1    script1     5    7    10:30   j_doe     2021-05-01    NULL    0    main_server
2    script1     8    4    10:29   j_doe     2021-05-03    NUll    0    backup_server
3    script2    44    0    2:40    j_doe     2021-05-04    NULL    0    backup_server
4    script3     3    2    1:39    j_doe     2021-05-05    NULL    0    main_server
5    script2    43    1    2:40    j_doe     2021-05-05    NULL    0    main_server
6    script3     5    0    1:38    j_doe     2021-06-01    NULL    0    backup_server
7    script4    15    0    0:50    j_doe     2021-07-05    NULL    0    main_server
8    script4    15    0    0:50    j_doe     2021-07-05    NULL    0    main_server
```

**Desired Results:**

```
2    script1     8    4    10:29   j_doe     2021-05-03    NUll    0    backup_server
5    script2    43    1    2:40    j_doe     2021-05-05    NULL    0    main_server
6    script3     5    0    1:38    j_doe     2021-06-01    NULL    0    backup_server
8    script4    15    0    0:50    j_doe     2021-07-05    NULL    0    main_server
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You can probably simplify the question as well.  All the columns, for instance, don't seem to be needed.

Comment: Thank you.  I provided some sample data.  I do, actually need all the columns to appear in the view as they are used by some of our software to select scripts to run, used by other developers, and for reporting.

Comment: If say script 1 runs twice on the same day, will the 2 rows be identical? Or would data in some of the columns be different?

Comment: If script1 runs twice on the same day, the view does display different pks, but the rest of the data appears to be the same (this is likely legitimate--script runs tend to produce the same/similar results)--it's just that only one, latest, result for each script_name should appear.

Comment: On your script_history table do you have an index? if not, having one on the PK covering the execution_date DESCENDING could be of great help to improve your performances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I think should look like this, where we get the maximum execution date, and if there are duplicates, we get the maximum pk.

```
SELECT ScriptHistory.*
FROM ScriptHistory

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ScriptHistory.Script_name, ScriptHistory.execution_date, MAX(pk) AS MaxPK
  FROM ScriptHistory

  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Script_name, Max(execution_date) AS MaxDate
    FROM ScriptHistory
    GROUP BY Script_name
  ) AS A on A.Script_name = ScriptHistory.Script_name
  AND A.MaxDate = ScriptHistory.execution_date

  GROUP BY ScriptHistory.Script_name, ScriptHistory.execution_date

) AS B on B.Script_name = ScriptHistory.Script_name
AND B.execution_date = ScriptHistory.execution_date
AND B.MaxPK = ScriptHistory.pk
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try defining a test view with this, but I receive an error #1060 "Duplicate column name 'Script_name'

Comment: I have changed the beginning `SELECT`, try again?